# Can't install any app, App Store asks for credit card

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, install

I haven't been installing anything on my iPad Mini for the past few weeks. But previously, I just had to tap on "Install", enter my Apple ID password and go.

Now, for every new application, even those free ones, I have to confirm each time, that I'm 17 or over. And then App Store asks to enter my credit card information. If I disagree and hit "Cancel", installation process is interrupted and I can't install any application, even free one.

I don't trust Apple at all and I'm not willing to share my credit card information, especially that I'm installing only free applications.

I'm pretty sure that I haven't changed anything in the configuration of my iPad Mini for ages.

Am I missing some significant change to the App Store or this is some kind of bug or virus? Is there anything I can do in this situation? How can I install a free application from the App Store, without having to share my credit card information with Apple?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to select that you don't have/want a payment option.

1. Navigate to this magic link on iOS or macOS:
   https://apps.apple.com/account/billing
2. Remove all payment types from the list and choose **None** as the payment type.

---

If you're not able to select None or the None option is not present for you to select, there are some possible reasons as to why this is the case:

- Unpaid balance
- Changed country/region
- Family Sharing management

For more information, see the Apple KB article:

- [Why can’t I select None when I edit my Apple ID payment information?](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203905)

If you want to create a new Apple ID with None as the payment method, purchase a free app from the App Store and choose Create Apple ID. For more information, see:

- [Create an iTunes Store, App Store, or iBooks Store account without a credit card or other payment method](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204034)

Comment: Settings → iTunes & App Stores does not exist.

Comment: Let we see if I have this right. Before I can install anything (without revealing my secrets), I need to install itunes (this looks like a boot strap problem).

Comment: @ctrl iTunes in ‘iTunes and App Stores’ refers to iTunes Store, as in ‘iTunes [and App] Stores’, not iTunes the deprecated app. In iOS 14 the option has moved, but there’s a link you can use on both iOS 13 and 14 to take you to the right place; I’ve edited my answer to replace the instructions with that link.