# Unable to update apps due to (unknown) payment issue

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, accounts

My credit card on file expired and I will not be replacing it.  I selected the "None" payment option as per this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115628/168832).  However, none of the apps (all free apps) will update anymore as it reports a billing problem.

I have:

- Checked all devices on my account and confirmed they only have free apps
- Never used subscriptions of any sort

How can I get iOS to once again update my apps?

It'd be nice to identify whatever the billing issue is and get it corrected (as there shouldn't be any billing going on whatsoever).  The biggest thing is though, apps (even though they're free!) won't update.

Comment: Have you tried signing out of your iTunes account and back in, since changing your payment method to `None`? **Settings** → **iTunes & App Store**.

Comment: I've clarified the edit you made and reopened this question. I agree you should now try what @Phong suggests above. However, in the event that doesn't work, you may get a faster resolution contacting Apple directly about this, because the issue could be at their end.